# Как сохранять значения в словаре, содержащееся в переменной // Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, словарь

У меня есть две переменные **znach** и **kluch**

Их значения, я получаю от пользователя.
Допустим пользователь вводит их значения, нужно, чтобы они сохранялись в словарь(zhach как значение, kluch как ключ)
Это сделать нетрудно, но когда пользователь вводит второй раз значения переменных, то в словаре не появляются новые значения, а просто старые заменяются новыми.

*Как сделать так, чтобы и старые значения оставались в словаре, и новые добавлялись каждый раз, когда их введёт пользователь?*

```
elif message.text.startswith("Если сообщение равно"):
        global keys
        global value
        global command
        keys= re.findall(r'равно (.*?) отправить',message.text)
        keys = ''.join(keys)
        value = re.findall(r'текст (.*?);',message.text)
        value = ''.join(value)
        command = {}
        command[keys] = value
```

Comment: Вы имеете в виду про одинаковые ключи?

Comment: Сделать очень просто - найти в справке функцию, которая добавляет в словарь ключ-значение и применить её. Примеров в сети полно. Почему ваш код так не делает, сказать невозможно, потому что у хрустального шара уже закончился рабочий день, а свой код вы не показываете. (хотя у меня есть версия)

Comment: код добавил в вопрос

Comment: вы переопределяете словарь когда делаете `command = {}`

Comment: мистер @SergFSM, мало того что переопределяет, еще и не понимает, что нове значение по одному и тому же ключу заменяет старое значение...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строчку `command = {}` нужно перенести в самое начало кода.